# Why does set command shows different value of PATHEXT variable than what's in the registry?

Tags: windows, windows-registry, environment-variables

I'm on Windows Vista x64.

```
C:\Users\Piotr>set pathext
PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.JS;.WS;.MSC
```

As far as I know value of PATHEXT environment variable is saved in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment` and `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment` keys under `PATHEXT` entry. In my case the first entry is `.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC;.PY;.PYW` and the second one does not exist.

Why there's a difference between what `set` command shows and what's in the registry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my question I stated

> In my case the first entry is
>   .COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC;.PY;.PYW and the
>   second one does not exist.

which wasn't true. In fact I had `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment\PATHEXT` entry and it was **empty**. It looks like having this entry empty somehow resets `PATHEXT` to some default value effectively eliminating any extra values added to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment\PATHEXT`.

Comment: The user environment overrides (has a higher priority than) the system environment.

Comment: The 'default' string you are seeing matches the PATHEXT policy template. Do you have a Domain Policy setting or Local Policy setting for PATHEXT?